# Reference to StructureMap container in concrete type

Tags: c#, structuremap

I'm designing a simple aspects framework using the DynamicProxy stuff and StructureMap and I've run up against an issue. I have the following method in my Registry:

```
public T AddAspectsTo<T>(T concreteObject)
{
    ProxyGenerator dynamicProxy = new ProxyGenerator();
    return (T)dynamicProxy.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTargetInterface(typeof(T)
    ,concreteObject,
    new[] { (IInterceptor)new AspectInterceptor(attributeMap) });
}
```

Which allows me to write code like:

```
For<ITestClass>().Use<TestClass>().EnrichWith(AddAspectsTo<ITestClass>);
```

The important thing is that I'm creating a concrete version of AspectInterceptor. In that class I need to grab items from the IoC container, but at this point I don't know about the IContainer object.

I won't need access to the IoC container until the resulting ITestClasses are in use and so the IContainer will have been created, but can't figure out how to grab the instance?

To be clear, I'm talking about cases here where we setup the structuremap container with:

```
IContainer container = new Container(new ItemWithPropertiesRegistry());
```

rather than the standard ObjectFactory stuff, which  works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The instance to enrich is available via a lambda:

```
For<ITestClass>().Use<TestClass>().EnrichWith(x => AddAspectsTo<ITestClass>(x));
```

Comment: Its actually the instance of the IContainer object I'm after, rather than the instance of the class being instantiated, I've added to the question to try and clarify.